# Class not always applied when user is at top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code to apply different classes to #nav depending if the user scrolls UP, DOWN, or is at the top of the page.

- .nav-down applied when user scrolls up
- .nav-up applied when user scrolls down
- .nav-down-top when user scrolls to the top of the page

code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var didScroll;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight(true);

$(window).scroll(function(event) { didScroll = true; });

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 100);

function hasScrolled() {
  if($( window ).width() > 768) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
       return;
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    // Scroll Down
    $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-down').removeClass('nav-down-top').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
    // Scroll Up (@ top of screen)
    if (st === 0) {
        $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-down-top');
   } else { //if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('#s-nav').removeClass('nav-up').removeClass('nav-down-top').addClass('nav-down');
    }
}
}
  lastScrollTop = st;
}

});
```

The problem is that when the user is at the top of the page or scrolls to the top .nav-down-top doesn't always get applied. This often happens when the user doesn't scroll very far to get to the top. I'm not sure how to ensure that .nav-down-top is applied when the user is at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 300;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
           $('.navbar-fixed').addClass('class');
        }
        else {
            $('.navbar-fixed').removeClass('oneclass');
            $('.navbar-fixed').addClass('otherclass');
        }
  });
function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
});
```

Try this script cleaner and tell me if it worked

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is this:

```
var el = $('#test1')
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
    console.log("addClass")
    $(el).addClass('slideUp');
  } else {    
    console.log("removeClass")
    $(el).removeClass('slideUp');
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0nz41ep/1/

You do not need to set an interval for the window to check the information, since the scroll is already an event that checks the window whenever you input information. :)

Also, are you doing animations?

You need to tell the CSS file that the divs you want to manipulate will be animated.

```
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; // Chrome
  -moz-transition: all 1s; // Mozilla
  -o-transition: all 1s; // Opera
  transition: all 1s;
```

If it's just one div add it to the id for the div, if it's multiple, add it to a class and add the class to all of the divs. The rest of the code should do the magic!

Comment: Right right, I definitely read that wrong, lol. There is some transitions not animations. It just seems that sometimes when the user scrolls to the top. the .nav-down-top class doesn't get added as it should

Comment: Your code experiences the same issue as mine. try scrolling down only a little bit then scroll up. The code does not apply, even when the 50 value is lowered

Comment: Nope. Works perfectly. Which browser are you using and which version? Check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J-Jty_WKRc